# How can I store a Dictionary of type [String: UIImage] into CoreData/UserDefaults?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a Dictionary `offlineImages = [String: UIImage]()` and I want to store it into CoreData/UserDefaults. How can I do this and what is the best choice?

Tried using filesystem but the images won't show (the `offlineImages` array contains local URLs for images):

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "offlineCell")
    let mainImageView = cell?.viewWithTag(2) as! UIImageView
    let mainImageURL = offlineImages[indexPath.row]
    let mainImageData = NSData(contentsOf: mainImageURL)
    let mainImage = UIImage(data: mainImageData! as Data)
    mainImageView.image = mainImage
    return cell!
}
```

Comment: Don't. Write the images to the filesystem. And never write that much data to NSUserDefaults. It's meant for little bits of data.

Comment: @rmaddy, and how can I store it into CoreData?

Comment: You don't. Write images to the file system. Just store filenames in core data.

Comment: I tried this but trying to show image by its local URL did nothing.

Comment: No one can help with that unless you update your question with relevant code and specific details about what you tried.

Comment: Just as @rmaddy mentioned, create a image folder on your filesystem, then save the images there, keep its URL/filename in your coredata as string.

Comment: Tried this. The images won't show when trying to show them from local URL.

Comment: @abcd can you show code where you save image to filestystem and save  them to local url. Likely when u reload u may need absolute path.

Comment: @NSGangster, updated the question.

Comment: @abcd where is the code that puts these url's into nsuserdefaults/coredata'

Comment: @NSGangster, didn't know how to do that so just used FileManager.

Comment: @abcd ok try creating image like this

`let mainImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: mainImageURL.absoluteString)`

Comment: @NSGangster, tried that now, same result, the images won't show.

Comment: Is the mainImageView visible? Is it within the coordinates of its parent view and is the size > 0,0?

Comment: @MirekE, yes, it is.

Answer (score 0):

In .xcdatamodeld file create attribute for your dictionary with type Transformable. Then in generated Entity subclass change type from id to Dictionary

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what "generated CoreData subclass" means.

Comment: After you set up your entities with attributes you need to generate subclasses for them. Did you do this?

Comment: Not yet. I don't exactly know how to use CoreData. I've seen a tutorial but it was just for Strings.

Answer (score -1):

You can convert Image into NSData and store into CoreData (Binary Data) like this

```
 NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

 [selectedObject setValue:imageData forKey:@"imageEntity"]; // selectedObject refers to NSManagedObject
```

And fetch Image

```
NSManagedObject *selectedObj = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[selectedObject valueForKey:@"image"]];
[self.imageView setImage:image]
```